# Bottom Padding Approach Does not work for Equal Height Div

Tags: html, css

I want to make two divs equal heights – left and right divs.

I referred the following posts and found a bottom padding approach.

1. [How do I achieve equal height divs (positioned side by side) with HTML / CSS ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056212/how-do-i-achieve-equal-height-divs-with-html-css)
2. [CSS: How to make left float div to adjust height dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331717/css-how-to-make-left-float-div-to-adjust-height-dynamically)

I tried to apply this concept in my page; but it doesn’t work correctly. On top of the right div there is unwanted space. How can we rectify it?

[image]

CODE

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<style type="text/css">
    .myContent {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid violet;
        min-width: 1210px;
    }

    .myHeader {
        width: 100%;
        /*width: 1200px;*/
        clear: both;
        background-color: #DFE8EF;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .leftPart {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
        background-color: silver;
    }

    .rightPart {
        border: 1px solid orange;
        background-color: beige;
        float: left;
        min-width: 1000px;
        /*
        margin-bottom: -1000px;
        padding-bottom: 1000px;
        margin-right: -5000px;
        padding-right: 5000px;
    */
    }
</style>

<html>
<head>
    <title>UpdateAccrualByItem</title>


    <link href="Content/MasterLayoutStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="body">
        <div class="myContent">

            <div class="myHeader">
                <img src="/Images/logo_header.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="leftPart">
                Menu
            </div>
            <div class="rightPart">

                <h2>UpdateAccrualByItem</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, but just have a few little things wrong.

You don't need a width for the right column, just the default `width:auto`. I used the same negative margin and padding trick to make the right column's height the size of the left's height and also to give the right column the illusion of taking up the rest of the space. You also should float the right container and take away the margin. You can remove the `clear:both` of the left column because it's not used

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jnbA/)

```
.leftPart {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color: orange;
}
.rightPart {
    border: 1px solid orange;  
    background-color: beige;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-right: -5000px;
    padding-right: 5000px;
}
```

**Edit**

You might also add some type of `@media` query to allow adjusting the window to look more smooth. [**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jnbA/1/). It's semi-hard coded based on the text length in the example, but on your final product it might be something you add on at the end

Comment: Apologies for unmarking the answer. I updated the question. It doesn't work with that layout. I need to have the min-width. Any resolution with this?

Comment: So when the window is smaller than 1200px, the min-width of the right element plus the width of the left element, do you want a scrollbar to come up? Do you want the content outside the window hidden? What behavior do you want?

Comment: When the window width is less than 1200px, remianing items need to be `hidden`.

Comment: If that's the case, is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/9jnbA/2/) what you're looking for? If not, perhaps it is something more like [**this instead**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/9jnbA/3/)? You're still not very clear